# Sql server migration to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a mssql dump script test.sql with store PROCEDURE how can I convert it to MYSQL sql file.
I checked [Sqline](http://www.sqlines.com/download) but it gives alot of error.Any help should be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you will find a tool to just convert that. There are a number of datatypes that don't have an exact match. You will have to put eyes on it at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Workbench has [migration capabilities](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-mssql.html). There are also 3rd party tools for database migration (e.g. https://dbconvert.com/mssql/mysql/?DB=6) and script conversion (e.g. http://burrist.com/index.php/ms-sql-server-to-mysql-conversion/).

Note that migrations of any kind can be tricky. Syntax is relatively easy but semantics can trip things up without you realizing it. Evaluate the tools carefully to determine which one provides the best/most help. It's rare for automated migrations/conversions to be 100% complete or accurate even if you have a very simple schema and are using ANSI standard SQL only (each vendor supports a varying level of ANSI standards). Test, test, test.